# VBA get windows first and last name of user

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to get the first and last name of a windows user.

The username is in cell A2 like:

SmithD

The code works but it puts the user's last name seperated by a comma and then their first name. I.e:

Smith, Dave

I want to change this to look like:

Dave.Smith and then add @inbox.com

So:

Dave.Smith@inbox.com

```
Sub Test()
    strUser = Range("A2").Value
    struserdn = Get_LDAP_User_Properties("user", "samAccountName", strUser, "displayName")
    If Len(struserdn) <> 0 Then
        MsgBox struserdn
    Else
        MsgBox "No record of " & strUser
    End If
End Sub

Function Get_LDAP_User_Properties(strObjectType, strSearchField, strObjectToGet, strCommaDelimProps)

' This is a custom function that connects to the Active Directory, and returns the specific
' Active Directory attribute value, of a specific Object.
' strObjectType: usually "User" or "Computer"
' strSearchField: the field by which to seach the AD by. This acts like an SQL Query's WHERE clause.
'             It filters the results by the value of strObjectToGet
' strObjectToGet: the value by which the results are filtered by, according the strSearchField.
'             For example, if you are searching based on the user account name, strSearchField
'             would be "samAccountName", and strObjectToGet would be that speicific account name,
'             such as "jsmith".  This equates to "WHERE 'samAccountName' = 'jsmith'"
' strCommaDelimProps: the field from the object to actually return.  For example, if you wanted
'             the home folder path, as defined by the AD, for a specific user, this would be
'             "homeDirectory".  If you want to return the ADsPath so that you can bind to that
'             user and get your own parameters from them, then use "ADsPath" as a return string,
'             then bind to the user: Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strReturnADsPath)

' Now we're checking if the user account passed may have a domain already specified,
' in which case we connect to that domain in AD, instead of the default one.
    If InStr(strObjectToGet, "\") > 0 Then
        arrGroupBits = Split(strObjectToGet, "\")
        strDC = arrGroupBits(0)
        strDNSDomain = strDC & "/" & "DC=" & Replace(Mid(strDC, InStr(strDC, ".") + 1), ".", ",DC=")
        strObjectToGet = arrGroupBits(1)
    Else
        ' Otherwise we just connect to the default domain
        Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
        strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    End If

    strBase = "<LDAP://" & strDNSDomain & ">"
    ' Setup ADO objects.
    Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set ADOConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    ADOConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    ADOConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    adoCommand.ActiveConnection = ADOConnection


    ' Filter on user objects.
    'strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
    strFilter = "(&(objectClass=" & strObjectType & ")(" & strSearchField & "=" & strObjectToGet & "))"

    ' Comma delimited list of attribute values to retrieve.
    strAttributes = strCommaDelimProps
    arrProperties = Split(strCommaDelimProps, ",")

    ' Construct the LDAP syntax query.
    strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"
    adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
    ' Define the maximum records to return
    adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
    adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False

    ' Run the query.
    Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute
    ' Enumerate the resulting recordset.
    strReturnVal = ""
    Do Until adoRecordset.EOF
        ' Retrieve values and display.
        For intCount = LBound(arrProperties) To UBound(arrProperties)
            If strReturnVal = "" Then
                strReturnVal = adoRecordset.Fields(intCount).Value
            Else
                strReturnVal = strReturnVal & vbCrLf & adoRecordset.Fields(intCount).Value
            End If
        Next
        ' Move to the next record in the recordset.
        adoRecordset.MoveNext
    Loop

    ' Clean up.
    adoRecordset.Close
    ADOConnection.Close
    Get_LDAP_User_Properties = strReturnVal

End Function
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: You should declare your local variables and your functions' return types and parameters. Without `Option Explicit` specified at the top of a module, VBA will happily compile a typo, which makes problems much harder to debug than necessary. Now, seems you're fetching the `DisplayName` property, which can reasonably be assumed to be "Smith, Dave". Have you tried enumerating the properties and seeing if there wasn't another one that would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

> *Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?*

You're asking for the `displayName`, and that's what you're getting ("Doe, John"). What you want is *not* the "display name", but the user's first and last name.

Let's look at the signature for the function you've got here:

```
Function Get_LDAP_User_Properties(strObjectType, strSearchField, strObjectToGet, strCommaDelimProps)
```

That last parameter is named `strCommaDelimProps`, short for "string, comma-delimited property names".

If you *look* at what it's doing with the `strCommaDelimProps` you're giving it, you'll notice it's concatenated into the `strQuery` that's sent to the LDAP server, and then it's also turned into an array named `arrProperties` (gosh dat Hungarian naming):

```
arrProperties = Split(strCommaDelimProps, ",")
```

Then it loops through the query results and...

```
strReturnVal = strReturnVal & vbCrLf & adoRecordset.Fields(intCount).Value
```

That's right, it appends each field value to the `strReturnVal` string, with each result separated by a `vbCrLf`.

So if you were to give the function two properties separated by commas, it would return you a string with the two values, separated by `vbCrLf` characters. That would look something like this:

```
"John[CRLF]
Doe"
```

So you take that string, `Split` it on `vbCrLf` to make an array, and `Join` it using a dot delimiter (`.`):

```
strParts = Get_LDAP_User_Properties("user", "samAccountName", strUser, "givenName,sn")
arrParts = Split(strParts, vbCrLf) 'splits the string into an array
result = Join(arrParts, ".") 'joins array elements back into a string
```

The two properties are, per [cyboashu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41471211/1188513), `"givenName"` and `"sn"`, so you give the function `"givenName,sn"` for the last parameter.

At that point the `result` string looks something like `John.Doe`; you might want to make that lowercase before you concatenate the `@inbox.com` part:

```
result = LCase$(result) & "@inbox.com"
MsgBox result
```

---

As for *what am I doing wrong?*, the latest [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/List) (my little pet project) can help you pinpoint a few things:

```
Warning: 'Vbnullstring' preferred to empty string literals - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 69
Warning: 'Vbnullstring' preferred to empty string literals - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 73
Warning: Parameter 'strObjectType' is implicitly Variant - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 11
Warning: Parameter 'strSearchField' is implicitly Variant - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 11
Warning: Parameter 'strObjectToGet' is implicitly Variant - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 11
Warning: Parameter 'strCommaDelimProps' is implicitly Variant - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 11
Warning: Member 'Range' implicitly references ActiveSheet - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 2
Hint: Member 'Test' is implicitly public - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 1
Hint: Member 'Get_LDAP_User_Properties' is implicitly public - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 11
Hint: Parameter 'strObjectType' is implicitly passed by reference - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 11
Hint: Parameter 'strSearchField' is implicitly passed by reference - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 11
Hint: Parameter 'strObjectToGet' is implicitly passed by reference - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 11
Hint: Parameter 'strCommaDelimProps' is implicitly passed by reference - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 11
Hint: Return type of member 'Get_LDAP_User_Properties' is implicitly 'Variant' - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 11
Error: Option Explicit is not specified in 'Module1' - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 1
Error: Local variable 'strUser' is not declared - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 2
Error: Local variable 'struserdn' is not declared - (Book2) VBAProject.Module1, line 3
```

Comment: Huh, looks like there's a bug in the "undeclared variable" inspection, it should be firing much more results than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways. 1. Split the displayName on "," and re-arrange.

```
 struserdn = Get_LDAP_User_Properties("user", "samAccountName", strUser, "displayName")
    struserdn = Split(struserdn, ",")(1) & Space(1) & Split(struserdn, ",")(0)
```

2.You can get First Name and Last Name in seperate calls using `GivenName` and `sn` params.

`strFirstName = Get_LDAP_User_Properties("user", "samAccountName", strUser, "givenName")
    strLastName = Get_LDAP_User_Properties("user", "samAccountName", strUser, "sn")`

But thi smethod will make twice the use of resources.

**Edit :**

*As per Matt's comment.*

Change this line

```
strReturnVal = strReturnVal & vbcrlf & adoRecordset.Fields(intCount).Value
```

To

```
strReturnVal = strReturnVal & "." & adoRecordset.Fields(intCount).Value
```

and then this will give you the full name in just one call.

```
 strFullName = Get_LDAP_User_Properties("user", "samAccountName", strUser, "givenName,sn")
```

Comment: *But this method will make twice the use of resources* - OP's function takes a *comma-separated list of properties*... and returns the values separated by a `vbCrLf`. You could just specify "givenName,sn" for the last parameter and split the returned string on `vbCrLf`, then join with a dot and add the `@inbox.com`, making one single call to `Get_LDAP_User_Properties`.

Comment: Not quite - I don't think `Get_LDAP_User_Properties` needs any modifications done (well other than declaring its locals and its return type and its parameters' types, and the params should be passed `ByVal`).. in fact doing that could be harmful if the function is used elsewhere for other purposes. What I meant was `result = Join(Split(Get_LDAP_User_Properties("user", "samAccountName", strUser, "givenName,sn"), vbCrLf), ".") & "@inbox.com"`

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to get the username of the user.

```
Option Explicit
Public strUser As String
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim strUser

    strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName

End Sub
```

Comment: I think OP is looking to get the user name, based on the value in a cell. This may or may not necessarily be the active user, unless I misunderstand the question.